# In which situations should I use a transpiler in javascript?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler

According to wikipedia:

> A source-to-source compiler, transcompiler or transpiler is a type of compiler that takes the source code of a program written in one programming language as its input and produces the equivalent source code in another programming language.

But in which situations a software development team should use a transpiler in the build workflow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a transpiler any time you want to use syntactic sugar which the target language doesn't support.

Comment: There are [many different languages that compile to JavaScript](https://github.com/bkeepers/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS), so it depends on which languages you're working with. You can also [translate JavaScript into various other languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22javascript+to+(c+OR+ruby+OR+python+OR+c%2B%2B+OR+java+OR+javascript+OR+lua+OR+c%23+OR+haxe+OR+perl)+(compiler+OR+converter+OR+translator+OR+transpiler)%22+-wikipedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building an application with JavaScript there are two main reasons why you would want two transpile your code.

### 1. You are using a language that is not JavaScript but is meant to be compiled to Javascript

This would be the case of something like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) or [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). Those cannot be executed directly on any platform, therefore your code has to be compiled first to plain JavaScript.

As for why you would want to use those languages. Mainly because they offer more features than JavaScript, like a type system, lots of syntactic sugar, etc.

### 2. You are using plain JavaScript, but using modern features of the language that are not available on your target platform.

For example, imagine you want to write your code using ES6 features but you want your clients to be able to use the app on IE11. In that case you would need a transpiler to transform your code into pure ES5 in a way that behaves identically.

This second point also relates strongly to polyfills. But those are out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a feature that it not supported in all browser yet. I.e.: promises, destructuring, generators etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: it depends on what you want to do, it depends on your team, our project, your boss, your vision.

To me the question is not  "why should I use a transpiler" but "what is the best technology I want to use regarding my skills and my team skills". For example, if you have a Ruby program, it's easier to use CoffeeScript (I don't know well Ruby world), if you have a huge Java background, you should consider [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) or [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home)…

Javascript is the web "lingua franca". If you want to apply other concepts than those present in Javascript or you want to use another kind of syntax or paradigm, you should use a transpiler.

For example: [Cappuccino](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/) with Objective-J, Google with [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/), CoffeeScript (Rubish syntax for javascript), Typescript which is ES7 with type, Eml (functional programming with Haskell like syntax), Babel which transpile ES7 to ES5 and so on.

There's also hidden transpiler. Vue.js, React or Flow for example (Angular 4 use not hidden transpiler).

Writing a good interpreter with a good JIT compiler is much more difficult to do and takes so much more time than writing a poorly designed language transpiler to Javascript which always performs better than yours. This is the case with Vala which transpile in C and let the GCC *and* gobject do the best of the job.

Also and it's much more important that there will be the standard problem. If you are a Forth lover, you can write your application in Forth and then transpile it to ES3 to be compatible with all (normal) browsers on the planet without unwanted plugin installation.